# Loop em PHP para verificar id do usuário

Tags: php, funções, while, id

Estou tentando criar uma função em PHP onde verifica se o id do usuário já existe, o id é criado com a função `rand`, mas mesmo tendo muita poucas chances de aparecer o mesmo id, as chances ainda existem! então para nunca ter dor de cabeça com essa parte, tenho que verificar se o id já foi inserido.

O que estou tentando fazer é:

Verificar se o id já existe:
se sim, gera um novo id e verifica novamente.
se não, segue o código.

Como criar isto da maneira certa?

```
$id_usuario = rand(1000000, 9999999);
$consultaBanco = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT id_usuario FROM site_user WHERE id_usuario = '".$id_usuario."'") or die (mysqli_error($consultaBanco));
$verificaBanco = mysqli_num_rows($consultaBanco);


if ($verificaBanco > 0){
   $id_usuario = rand(1000000, 9999999);
   return $consultaBanco;
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil setar na tabela `site_user` a coluna `id_usuario` como `AUTO_INCREMENT` ? Pois assim não tem como ter **id** repetida!

Comment: Se restarem poucos nesse rand vai dar trabalho até achar um não repetido! Imagine se restar apenas um. Solução do @wmsouza é a melhor possível, segue o código e deixe o banco gerar o id

Comment: Esse `id_usuario` precisa (ou vai) ser utilizado diretamente pelo usuario (algo que ele precisa decorar)? ou vai ser visivel apenas para o sistema?

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que o motivo para você estar fazendo esse sorteio é que você quer um id com 7 digitos (no formato **xxxxxxx**). O que a primeira vista não seria possivel com uma chave primaria auto incremento no banco de dados (mas só a primeira vista).

Você pode setar de onde o auto incremento vai começar (por exemplo, a partir de 1000000). Isso pode ser feito assim (executando na interface de administração do banco, por exemplo no phpmyadmin, se você estiver usando, ou pelo terminal, ou até mesmo pelo codigo php (apenas uma vez!)):

```
ALTER TABLE site_user AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

Isso vai fazer com que tudo que for inserido com o **insert** seja incrementado a partir do valor setado na instrução acima.

Mas só tem um problema, se o campo id usuario ainda não for chave primaria, o auto incremento não funcionara. Então temos que torna-la chave primaria (se ainda não for):

```
ALTER TABLE site_user ADD PRIMARY KEY(id_usuario);
```

E por fim dizer que **id_usuario** é `auto_increment`. Mais ou menos assim:

```
ALTER TABLE site_user MODIFY COLUMN id_usuario AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Depois de tudo isso você pode fazer os inserts sem ter que se preocupar em fazer sorteio.

Comment: essa parte eu conheço, mas realmente preciso do rand para criar um id único para o usuário que não seja em sequencia, sim, aleatório